# Get initial state of ReactJs button from database

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im very new to ReactJs and wonder how I can set the initial state of a button component depending on the sql database data?
I get the data via php & json and it works fine but I just can't get how to set the state.
every tip is appreciated!
Thanks

```
var OutfitList = React.createClass({
      render: function() {
        var outfitNodes = this.props.data.map(function (data) {
          return (
            <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 singleOutfit" style={{background: '#e5e5e5'}}>
              <data author={data.author}>
                <img src={data.url}/>
                <div className='row subImage'>
                  <div className='col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4'>
                    <div className={data.fav == 1 ? 'isFav btn' : 'btn'}>Click To Fav</div>
                  </div>
                  <div className='col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 text-center'><h4>{data.title}</h4></div>
                  <div className='col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4'>{data.tags}</div>
                </div>
              </data>
            </div>
            );
        });

        return (
          <div className="container">
            <div className="row">

              <h3>ALL</h3>

              {outfitNodes}

            </div>
          </div>
        );
      }
    });

    var App = React.createClass({
      loadOutfitsFromServer: function() {
        $.ajax({
          url: this.props.url,
          dataType: 'json',
          cache: false,
          success: function(data) {
            this.setState({data: data});
          }.bind(this),
          error: function(xhr, status, err) {
            console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
          }.bind(this)
        });
      },
      getInitialState: function() {
        return {data: []};
      },
      componentDidMount: function() {
        this.loadOutfitsFromServer();
        setInterval(this.loadOutfitsFromServer, this.props.pollInterval);
      },
      render: function() {
        return (
          <div>
          <OutfitList data={this.props.data} />
          </div>
        );
      }
    });

    React.render(
      <App data={data} pollInterval={2000} />,
      document.getElementById('content')
    );
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6ss41m50/

Comment: Can we see some code ?

Comment: hey @DavidJacquel i've added a brief jsfiddle now.

What I want is to click on the button and save the 1 or 0 to the database via json/php onclick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set some initial state use `getInitialState()`.  Whatever you return from this method is the initial state, which can thereafter be accessed with `this.state.buttonState` and modified with `this.setState()`.

Assuming your DB data is passed to this component as `buttonState`, you can set state like this:

```
...
getInitialState: function() {
    return {
        buttonState: this.props.buttonState
    }
}

render: function() {
    return {
       <div><button>this.state.buttonState</button></div>
    }
}
...
```

However, for an example like this, consider not even setting any state because it creates a [false source of truth](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/props-in-getInitialState-as-anti-pattern.html). Instead, you could just use the passed in data from your DB directly in the button.

```
render: function() {
    return {
        <div><button>this.props.buttonState</button></div>
    }   
}
```

Comment: thank you very much @arhoskins i've done it like the following now: <button className={data.fav == 1 ? 'fa fa-2x fa-heart favOne' : 'fa fa-2x fa-heart-o favZero'}></button> but my next question is how can i submit data.fav as liked onclick to my database? and render it as liked at same time?